# SQL Server2008: Finding the empty records

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a tableA which have 50 columns. 5 out of them are NOT NULL and other 45 can be NULL.
now. there is addition 51st column of status.

I want to flag the record as a "failure" in status
when col6-col50 are empty.

col1-col5 are always populated. but Lets say from col6-col50 are all null values, then flag the record as a failure in status.

Okay I know the lengthy way.

```
update ..
...
where (col6 is null and col7 is null and.....)
```

Is there any other possible shorter and efficient way ?
Thanks

Comment: I think your answers is going to be no.

Comment: Thats exactly what I thought.

Comment: "50 columns... 45 can be NULL... I want to flag the record...  I know the lengthy way..." -- if you are finding [SQL DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Manipulation_Language) difficult or a pain to write then you should be looking to change your [SQL DDL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Definition_Language).

Answer (score 1):

Not much better, but

```
update ..
...
where COALESCE(
   col6,
   col7,
   ...) IS NULL
```

Comment: Would COALESCE be more efficient than "IS NULL" ?

Comment: Should be very close, if not identical. (More efficient to maintain, I think.) But COALESCE has a big disadvantage: the fields must be the same datatype.

Comment: Thats what I figured out. Now switching all the codes to "IS NULL". Thanks anyways